# LEFT JOIN with SUM not returning correct values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb-10.1

I have an invoice table with various cost breakdowns.
I have a linked table with misc costs as well.
Relationship is 1 invoice to many misc costs

When I do a SUM() and multiple rows exist on misc costs table (RIGHT), the values in the invoice table (LEFT) are multiplied by the number of rows found.

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9CKGRShXPoT3k4Wcm83fVD/5

Original query with incorrect results for LABOUR, PARTS, POLS and SUBLET:

```
SELECT  SUM(ad.labour_cost) AS LABOUR,
    SUM(ad.part_cost) AS PARTS,
    SUM(ad.pol_cost) AS POLS,
    SUM(ad.sublet_cost) AS SUBLET,
    SUM(am.misc_sales_amt)  AS MISC
FROM AdvisorSalesData ad 
LEFT JOIN AdvisorMiscSalesData am 
  ON (ad.customer_id=am.customer_id AND ad.invoice_no=am.invoice_no)
WHERE ad.customer_id IN (3)
```

Adjusted query - Removed INNER JOIN and tried a single SELECT on the misc table with incorrect result for MISC (NULL):

```
SELECT  SUM(ad.labour_cost) AS LABOUR,
    SUM(ad.part_cost) AS PARTS,
    SUM(ad.pol_cost) AS POLS,
    SUM(ad.sublet_cost) AS SUBLET,
    (SELECT SUM(misc_sales_amt) FROM AdvisorMiscSalesData WHERE customer_id IN (3) AND invoice_no=ad.invoice_no ) AS MISC
FROM AdvisorSalesData ad 
WHERE ad.customer_id IN (3)
```

How can I adjust to get the correct results for all 5 columns in one single query?

Comment: one to many or many to many?

Comment: What are the expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT SUM(ad.labour) AS LABOUR,
       SUM(ad.parts) AS PARTS,
       SUM(ad.pols) AS POLS,
       SUM(ad.sublet) AS SUBLET,
       SUM(am.misc)  AS MISC
FROM (SELECT customer_id, invoice_no,
             SUM(ad.labour_cost) AS LABOUR,
             SUM(ad.part_cost) AS PARTS,
             SUM(ad.pol_cost) AS POLS,
             SUM(ad.sublet_cost) as sublet
      FROM AdvisorSalesData ad 
      GROUP BY customer_id, invoice_no
     ) ad LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT customer_id, invoice_no,
             SUM(am.misc_sales_amt) AS MISC
      FROM AdvisorMiscSalesData am 
      GROUP BY customer_id, invoice_no
     ) am
     ON ad.customer_id = am.customer_id AND    
        ad.invoice_no = am.invoice_no
WHERE ad.customer_id IN (3);
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9CKGRShXPoT3k4Wcm83fVD/5) is a db<>fiddle.

You can repeat the filter in the subqueries for better performance:

```
SELECT SUM(ad.labour) AS LABOUR,
       SUM(ad.parts) AS PARTS,
       SUM(ad.pols) AS POLS,
       SUM(ad.sublet) AS SUBLET,
       SUM(am.misc)  AS MISC
FROM (SELECT customer_id, invoice_no,
             SUM(ad.labour_cost) AS LABOUR,
             SUM(ad.part_cost) AS PARTS,
             SUM(ad.pol_cost) AS POLS,
             SUM(ad.sublet_cost) as sublet
      FROM AdvisorSalesData ad 
      WHERE ad.customer_id IN (3)
      GROUP BY customer_id, invoice_no
     ) ad LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT customer_id, invoice_no,
             SUM(am.misc_sales_amt) AS MISC
      FROM AdvisorMiscSalesData am 
      WHERE ad.customer_id IN (3)
      GROUP BY customer_id, invoice_no
     ) am
     ON ad.customer_id = am.customer_id AND    
        ad.invoice_no = am.invoice_no
WHERE ad.customer_id IN (3);
```

Comment: Gordon, correct fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9CKGRShXPoT3k4Wcm83fVD/6 you have to click update when done or else you are just copying the old one. Cheers

Comment: Ok. That returns the correct results - thanks ... BUT, when I add it back into my code it takes 269 seconds to execute....